# Calling Google Analytics with JavaScript vs. Google Measurment Protocol

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track events on a website (C# Asp.Net). For now, I am using JavaScript calls like this :

```
ga('send', 'event', 'log in', 'log in', 'User successfully logged in', 1);
```

for the tracking of events like the successful log in of a user.

I cannot directly call the JS from my C# classes logic so I set a session cookie to call the JS method on the landing page after log in.

Google Measurement Protocol allows to perform calls directly with HTTP Post requests as so:

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1             // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=event        // Event hit type
&ec=video       // Event Category. Required.
&ea=play        // Event Action. Required.
&el=holiday     // Event label.
&ev=300         // Event value.
```

In this example, is there any reason not to switch to using Google's measurement protocol rather than using workarounds to call the JS function?

Comment: No reason I can think of. Measurement Protocol works great and being able to send hits to GA server side is much better for what you're doing.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your comment. The only thing I could think of is performance. But I can make the post "async" to make sure I don't get longer load times.